# Appending and importing data

Tags: mysql

I am exporting from one table and importing to another table.

1. First i import 100 records, then i need to import next 500 records.
2. Instead of appending it imports that last 500 records, i want to append 100 +500 records.
3. Is there any option in that in mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to import this data?

Comment: 1. Write a select query to get 100 records insert into another table, export to excel, open the new table, import the data by right clicking. This i have to do for multiple times, so how its possible to append rows to the new table while importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about how to use the `LIMIT ... OFFSET` clause.  See the doc on [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for details.